# Using EventFiringWebDriver with RemoteWQebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, ui-automation

I want to use EventFiringWebDriver with RemoteWebDriver as we are using selenium grid, with WebDriver my code works fine but when I try to cast EventFiringWebDriver to RemoteWebDriver I am getting below exception at run time.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    at com.sixt.test.eventfiringwebdriver.DriverFactory.getDriverInstance(DriverFactory.java:52)
    at com.sixt.test.eventfiringwebdriver.DriverFactoryTest.test1(DriverFactoryTest.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Please help.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials

Comment: The error message is clear: you just can't. [_EventFiringWebDriver_](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) is not a subclass of [_RemoteWebDriver_](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html)...

Answer (score 0):

`EventFiringWebDriver` is not a subclass of `RemoteWebDriver`, so you can't directly cast it. It's a pretty rare circumstance that you'd ever need to use `RemoteWebDriver` directly, but if you're needing the driver instance that your event-firing wrapper is using, you can do the following:

```
// Note: Assume eventDriver is a valid EventFiringWebDriver instance
// Further note: Yes, it's possible to consolidate the below into fewer lines,
// but each step is shown here for clarity.
WrapsDriver wrapperAccess = (WrapsDriver)eventDriver;
WebDriver driver = wrapperAccess.getWrappedDriver();

// If you really, really need a RemoteWebDriver instance here, you can do this
RemoteWebDriver remoteDriver = (RemoteWebDriver)driver;
```

Comment: Hi Jim,
Thanks for your reply. I tried the code which you shared. Now i am not getting ClassCast exception, but my event listener is not getting called. 
              EventFiringWebDriver eDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(webDriver);
       eDriver.register(new WebDriverListener());
       //webDriver = eDriver;
       WrapsDriver wrapperAccess = (WrapsDriver)eDriver;
       webDriver= wrapperAccess.getWrappedDriver(); 
If i directly assign EventFiringWebDriver instance to WenDriver instance the listener works but if i try to do it thru WrapsDriver it does not work.

Comment: Or is there any way thru which i can use EventFiringWebDriver with RemoteWebDriver.

Comment: @Umang You’ve given no indication why you think you need access to the raw `RemoteWebDriver` instance, instead of using the `WebDriver` interface. That’s also part an entirely different question than the one you asked, which is why the `ClassCastException` is happening and how to avoid it.

Comment: In our framework we use selenium grid and so we use RemoteWebDriver not WebDriver, hence asked the above question.

Comment: @Umang That is irrelevant. You can use Selenium Grid, and `RemoteWebDriver` and still use the `WebDriver` interface. There is no need to use the concrete implementation; you should be using the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we need concrete implementation, for example:

- To have sessionID : `((RemoteWebDriver) webdriver).getSessionId()`
- To upload a file : `((RemoteWebDriver) webdriver).setFileDetector()`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 ((RemoteWebDriver) ((EventFiringWebDriver) this.browserContext.getDriver()).getWrappedDriver());
```

Answer (score 0):

it's working for me (kotlin)

```
val driver = (getWebDriver() as EventFiringWebDriver).wrappedDriver as RemoteWebDriver
val sessionId = driver.sessionId.toString()
```

note: i added listener like

```
@BeforeEach
    fun beforeEach() {
        WebDriverRunner.addListener(Highlighter())
    }
```